# Convert image to bitmap and compress

Tags: android, image, bitmap, compression, out-of-memory

I have a function convert image to array byte (to save image into database sqlite). I have a problem, how to compress image and avoid out of memory error? 
This is my code
Thanks in advance.

```
public byte[] ConverttoArrayByte(ImageView img)
{
    try{
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        Log.d("Tag", "Null");
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
   return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a small function that resizes the image:

```
public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        float bitmapRatio = (float)width / (float) height;
        if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
            width = maxSize;
            height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
        } else {
            height = maxSize;
            width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
        }
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
    }
```

And call this function in this way `Bitmap bitmap = GetAttachmentsUtils.getResizedBitmap(bitmap, maxSize);` to get the resized bitmap.

Then you can compress it using `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);` and perform the same operations you were doing previously.